# how can i use popup with active button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog

I used showModalBottomSheet but isn't useful

[image]

I used this code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeW8z.png)
what i want is to move modal from bottom and make floating button active above modal.

Code :

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.close),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("TEST"),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.filter),
        ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet instead of code-image that you.ve tried so far? And image that are you trying archive.